# not able to create controller by referencing to javascript file having module declared in it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created angular module in a javascript file app.js as below:

**var app = angular.module('myApp', []);**

Further i went to the controller folder of my project and added a javascript file for Controllers.
Next i referenced the already created app.js file(which is havning module creation) in the first step and then i tried to create controller using it as in below lines:

```
/// <reference path="app.js" />
app.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.tesdtata = 'test';
})
```

Now when i am binding the scope variable to UI and running the solution, i am getting exceptions as:  **'app' not defined**

Finally i am not able to vied the value of 'testdata' in browser.

Moreover when i type the line: app.controller(..)  the intellisence shows me some diffenet overload variables i.e. **app.controller(recepiename,factoryfunction)**   which is not correct.

Everything works fine if i create module individualy for every controller file and then using that create controller in same file. And problem occurs when i try to reference the single app.js file (having module creation it) and try to create controllers.

Comment: Can you show your HTML Code, the one where you have included all your dependencies and the one where u are trying to use the $scope variable?

Comment: Check the folder path while referencing definition files path : `/// <reference path="../app.js" />`

Answer (score 0):

Check if your UI(HTML file) looks something like this. That'll do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="control.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
        {{testdata}}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is discouraged to use global variables in javascript nowadays.

Instead of doing this

```
// app.js
var app = angular.module('myApp, []');

// controller.js
app.controller...
```

Do this

```
// app.js
var app = angular.module('myApp, []');

// controller.js
angular.module('myApp').controller...
```

Reference not needed and intellisense won't complain too.l